# how to mute speech synthesizer

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech

currently I am doing this.

```
func muteSpeaking(){
    let speechUtterance: AVSpeechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance()
    speechUtterance.volume = 0.0
}
```

what is wrong with this code

Comment: From taking a quick look at the docs "Setting this after enqueing the utterance has no effect."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to stop the speechSynthesizer.

```
 var speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
 speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
```